# Google Play Distributing to Phones only

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I read the guide [Distributing to Specific Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) and i tried both

```
<compatible-screens
   android:smallScreens="false"
   android:normalScreens="false" 
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

and

```
<supports-screens
   android:smallScreens="false"
   android:normalScreens="false" 
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

even combined (iknow... i know... :D)

But i can't seem to be able to limit my app from showing up in searches from my tablet (and of course it also installs)

The reverse setting works though..

```
<supports-screens
   android:smallScreens="false"
   android:normalScreens="false" 
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

my phone appears incompatible with the tablet version of the APK. What gives? is there something i'm not getting in the way that Google play filters using the Manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this syntax to filter, allowing distribution to only phones (and you can extrapolate and make the same for large and xlarge if you want to make a version for tablets).

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```